# Hide download indicator from the status bar

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to know how to hide download indicator from the status bar in Android.

My app sometimes downloads small files from the server. There are many small files, and as a result, the download indicator in the status bar ends up blinking almost indefinitely.

The download indicator is the first icon in the status bar, and everything else ends up being shifted back and forth while download indicator is being shown and hidden with very small interval.

Is it possible to hide this indicator programmatically, and what approach can I take?

I am using Cordova 5.3.3, and testing on Android 4.4.4 (KitKat).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using DownloadManager.Request you can use the following code to hide the download notification in the status bar.

```
final DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(uri));
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(VIDEO_PATH, VIDEO_NAME + VIDEO_TYPE);

final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(request);
```

It's really just that second line that hides it. I included the rest of the code for downloading a file as well.

**Edit**

From Android doc:

> If set to VISIBILITY_HIDDEN, this requires the permission android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION.

Comment: Thanks. I also discovered that you need an extra permission to do this. Please accept my edit request.

Comment: Hi, can't we do the same without permission? as we know if we ask user to accept this permission, it can make them think suspicious like why app wants to download without showing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
  DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
```

remove this line `//request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);`

```
 request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
```